# Using crontab to rsync files to Synology NAS, getting permissions error

Tags: cron, rsync, synology, nas

I am trying to backup my Linux system to my Synology NAS by using rsync in crontab.

I have used `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and then used `ssh-copy-id gage@192.168.0.235` to move the key over to the NAS.

I run `rsync -avx / gage@192.168.0.235:/volume1/homes/gage/Backups/parrot` and it works fine. I put the same command (plus an output to a log file) into crontab as the gage user and when I read the log file, the following is the output:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
gage@192.168.0.235: Permission denied (publickey,password).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(231) [sender=3.2.7]
```

I have tried using the root user on the local system and that also did not work.

I am still a novice to some of this, anyone know a solution?